# mongodb nested search query in java

Tags: java, mongodb, find, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have question regarding MongoDB search query. I have two parameters on which I have to search either "text" or "username" and some more parameters also there.

So the SQL query would be like this:

```
select * from tbl where  place='pune' and (gender='male' or type='life') and (text='hi' or username='hi')
```

How would it be in MongoDB?

Right now I am able to search with just one parameter:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            BasicDBList dbl = new BasicDBList();

if (cmodel.getGender() != null) {

    if ("male".equals(cmodel.getGender().toLowerCase())) {
        dbl.add(new BasicDBObject(CrushModel.COLUMN_GENDER, "male"));
    } else if ("female".equals(cmodel.getGender().toLowerCase())) {
        dbl.add(new BasicDBObject(CrushModel.COLUMN_GENDER, "female"));
    } else {
        dbl.add(new BasicDBObject(CrushModel.COLUMN_TYPE, "crush"));
    }

    dbl.add(new BasicDBObject(CrushModel.COLUMN_TYPE, "life"));
    query.put("$or", dbl);
}

query.put("text", new BasicDBObject("$regex", String.format(".*((?i)%s).*", searchText)));
query.put(CrushModel.COLUMN_PLACE, new ObjectId(cmodel.getPlace().toString()));
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);



db.test.find( { $and : [  {gender : 'male' },
    { place :'pune'},{$or:[{text:/abc0/},{userName:/abc0/}, {type : 'life' }]}] } )
```

this is not working the way i want it.

```
 there is one more field in table name "type" ,
for ex. if gender is male/female for which type is "normal" then i also want to show the type "life" here
    It is only showing me the either or result like the entries of all gender:male or only the entries of type "life", I want to show both of them.
```

Its working

```
db.test.find( { $and : [ { place : 'pune'},{$or:[{text:/hi u r looking awesome 10/},{userName:/hi u r looking awesome 10/}]},{$or:[{gender : 'male' },{type:'life'}]}] } )
```

thanks @Disposer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the mongo query is exactly:

```
db.test.find(  { $and : [  { gender : 'male' }, { place : 'pune' },  { $or : [  { text : 'hi' }, { username : 'hi' } ] }  ] }  )
```

The java would be:

```
ArrayList orList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList andList = new ArrayList();

orList.add(new BasicDBObject("text", "hi"));                  
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("username", "hi"));

andList.add(new BasicDBObject("gender", "male"));
andList.add(new BasicDBObject("place", "pune"));
andList.add(new BasicDBObject("$and", orList));

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", andList);
```

Comment: thanks for your resonse. I want to add one more parameter in query that is type ,for ex. if gender is male/female for which type is "normal" then i also want to show the type "life" here . I am trying query in this way but this is not giving me the exact result.                                          db.test.find( { $and : [  {gender : 'male' },
    { place :'pune'},{$or:[{text:/abc0/},{userName:/abc0/}, {type : 'life' }]}] } )  . please help.

Comment: Its working now thanks :) db.test.find( { $and : [  
    { place : 'pune'},{$or:[{text:/hi u r looking awesome 10/},{userName:/hi u r looking awesome 10/}]},{$or:[{gender : 'male' },{type:'life'}]}] } )

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut way of doing the above with MongoDB Java Driver v3.2.2. You can do something like this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(Document.parse("{$and: [{gender: 'male'}, {place: 'pune' }, {$or: [{text: 'hi'}, {username: 'hi'}]}]}"));
```

This should return the same result as above.